# Active Element JS for href="/"

Tags: javascript, html

I want to to add a "active" Class to the navigation element from the current page. It works fine except for the index page, I want to keep the a href="/" Link for the index site, because of SEO and aesthetics.

Any help?

```js
$(function() {
  var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
  $(".menu-side a").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '')
      $(this).addClass("active");
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="menu-side">
  <a title="Startseite" href="/">Startseite</a>
  <a title="Über Mich" href="ueber_mich.html">Über Mich</a>
  <a title="Projekte" href="projekte.html">Projekte</a>
  <a title="Galerie" href="galerie.html">Galerie</a>
  <a title="Kontakt" href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a>
  <a title="Impressum" href="impressum.html">Impressum</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: You can consider using a ul/ol and then using li:active property for this.

Example: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp

Comment: How does your home page looks like? `www.example.com`/`www.example.com/index.php?r=a/b`...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sessionStorage` to save the `href` of the element clicked, and when the page redirects, you reapply the *class* to the element with the saved `href` like so:

```
$("nav a").click(function() {
  $(this) siblings().removeClass("active").addClass("active");
  sessionStorage.nowActive = $(this).attr('href');
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  if (sessionStorage.nowActive != "undefined") {
    $("nav a").each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr("href") == sessionStorage.nowActive) {
        $(this).addClass("active");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** of the code](http://jsfiddle.net/kc50L10f/)

Comment: And when you initially open the page or come from an external url?

Comment: When you initially open the page or come from an external one, none would be highlighted :P

Comment: I know, it was a rhetorical question ;)

Comment: @Shomz Not gonna work :P Scope wasnt specified sooo... :P

Comment: There you go - accepted a non-working answer! ;)  My working one got unaccepted, of course! :D

Answer (score 1):

You can always check if an active class is set, and if not, set the default one:

```js
$(function() {
  var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
  $(".menu-side a").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '')
      $(this).addClass("active");
  })

  if($(".menu-side a.active").length == 0) 
        $(".menu-side a:first").addClass('active');

});
```

```css
a.active {color: green}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="menu-side">
  <a title="Startseite" href="/">Startseite</a>
  <a title="Über Mich" href="ueber_mich.html">Über Mich</a>
  <a title="Projekte" href="projekte.html">Projekte</a>
  <a title="Galerie" href="galerie.html">Galerie</a>
  <a title="Kontakt" href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a>
  <a title="Impressum" href="impressum.html">Impressum</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, easy to understand and worked for me pretty good.